# How to use promises with multiple calls to dynamodb scan

Tags: javascript, promise, amazon-dynamodb

I receive a promise from dynamodb.scan(). When the promise is resolved if the response includes LastEvaluatedKey then dynamodb.scan() must be called again. When the response does not include the LastEvaluatedKey object all records of the table have been scanned and the query complete. I do not know the number of calls to scan() needed in advance. I don't know how to code this. This is what I have now:

```
function scan(options, startKey) {
  var parms = {
    TableName: options.source,
    ProjectionExpression: "book, bid, #kee, #unt, pid, #txt",
    FilterExpression: "contains(#txt, :v_qs)",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#unt": "unit",
      "#txt": "text",
      "#kee": "key"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":v_qs": options.queryTransformed
    }
  };

  if (startKey) {
     parms.ExclusiveStartKey = startKey;
  }

  return dynamoDb.scan(parms).promise();
}

scan(options).then(function(response) {
  if (response.LastEvaluatedKey) {
    searchResults.push(response);
    return scan(options, response.LastEvaluatedkey);
  }
  else {
    return response
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  if (response.LastEvaluatedKey) {
    searchResults.push(response);
    return scan(options, response.LastEvaluatedKey);
  }
  else {
    return response;
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  //this is crazy - bailing even if another call is needed
  searchResults.push(response);
  return generateSearchResponse();
});
```

This clearly is not the way to do it. This code is part of a AWS Lambda node function. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function should be your friend. I can't test it myself, but something like this should work. Let me know if you encounter any error

```
function scan(options, startKey) {
  var parms = {
    TableName: options.source,
    ProjectionExpression: "book, bid, #kee, #unt, pid, #txt",
    FilterExpression: "contains(#txt, :v_qs)",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#unt": "unit",
      "#txt": "text",
      "#kee": "key"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":v_qs": options.queryTransformed
    }
  };

  if (startKey) {
     parms.ExclusiveStartKey = startKey;
  }

  return dynamoDb.scan(parms).promise();
}

function processResponse(options, response) {
    return (response && response.LastEvaluatedKey) ?
        scan(options, response.LastEvaluatedkey)
            .then(function(next_response) {
                return [response].concat(processResponse(next_response));
            })
        :
        Promise.resolve(response); // replace 'Promise' by whatever Promise library you are using (when, bluebird, ...)
}

scan(options)
    .then(processResponse.bind(null, options))
    .then(function(response_list) {
        // response_list is an array of response
        return generateSearchResponse();
    });
```